# How to make install-tl to produce pdflatex.fmt

Tags: texlive, installing, format-files

I'm using `install-tl` with the following profile:

```
selected_scheme scheme-basic
TEXDIR /path/to/build/texlive-basic
TEXMFLOCAL /path/to/build/texlive-basic/texmf-dist/texmf-local
TEXMFSYSVAR /path/to/build/texlive-basic/texmf-dist/texmf-var
TEXMFSYSCONFIG /path/to/build/texlive-basic/texmf-dist/texmf-config
collection-xetex 1
collection-luatex 1
```

It produces the following `*.fmt` files:

```
build/texlive-basic/texmf-dist/texmf-var/web2c/xetex/xelatex.fmt
build/texlive-basic/texmf-dist/texmf-var/web2c/xetex/xelatex-dev.fmt
build/texlive-basic/texmf-dist/texmf-var/web2c/xetex/xetex.fmt
build/texlive-basic/texmf-dist/texmf-var/web2c/tex/tex.fmt
build/texlive-basic/texmf-dist/texmf-var/web2c/luatex/dviluatex.fmt
build/texlive-basic/texmf-dist/texmf-var/web2c/luatex/optex.fmt
build/texlive-basic/texmf-dist/texmf-var/web2c/luatex/luatex.fmt
build/texlive-basic/texmf-dist/texmf-var/web2c/pdftex/etex.fmt
build/texlive-basic/texmf-dist/texmf-var/web2c/pdftex/pdfetex.fmt
build/texlive-basic/texmf-dist/texmf-var/web2c/pdftex/pdftex.fmt
build/texlive-basic/texmf-dist/texmf-var/web2c/luahbtex/luahbtex.fmt
```

The `fmtutil-sys --all` was indeed run: `running fmtutil-sys --no-error-if-no-engine=luajithbtex,luajittex,mfluajit --no-strict --all ...done`. There are no `...failed` messages.

When I try to compile a LaTeX file with `\documentclass` with `--fmt .../pdftex.fmt`, I get

```
This is pdfTeX, Version 3.141592653-2.6-1.40.22 (TeX Live 2021_busytexnative) (preloaded format=/home/runner/work/busytex/busytex/dist-native/pdftex.fmt)
entering extended mode
(./example.tex
! Undefined control sequence.
```

which probably means that LaTeX macros are not loaded in the format. Is it true?

How do I get `install-tl` to produce `pdflatex.fmt` and `lualatex.fmt`?

It seems that the problem is in [`fmtutil.pl`](https://github.com/TeX-Live/texlive-source/raw/trunk/texk/texlive/linked_scripts/texlive/fmtutil.pl) not discovering the engines correctly. How does `fmtutil.pl` discover engines? Should I add some environment variables for `fmtutil.pl`?

Somehow `collection-latex` (and `latex-bin`) isn't getting installed despite `scheme-basic`. How do I force `install-tl` to install it?

Comment: even if you had built the format if you process the document with `--fmt .../pdftex.fmt` that is explicitly specifying plain tex so latex documents would not work. I'm surprised starting from scheme-basic you got latex at all, you seem to have lualatex and xelatex but not pdflatex, perhaps because you specified those collections I'd have to check

Comment: If course I'd like to run with `--fmt .../pdflatex.fmt` at the end of the day :) I suspect `TEXMFSYSCONFIG` and the likes are set incorrectly... Btw `install-tl` indeed did install  `build/texlive-basic/texmf-dist/tex/latex/latexconfig/pdflatex.ini` and `build/texlive-basic/texmf-dist/tex/generic/tex-ini-files/lualatex.ini`, but it can't find them. OTOH `xelatex.ini` is installed at `/build/texlive-basic/texmf-dist/tex/generic/tex-ini-files/xelatex.ini`. Anything looking wrong in my profile?

Comment: `scheme-basic` (at https://tug.org/svn/texlive/trunk/Master/tlpkg/tlpsrc/scheme-basic.tlpsrc?revision=54191&view=co) indeed does contain `depend collection-latex`

Comment: yes saw that later, I give up, It must be possible to get it all configured but why bother, making the format is trivial `pdftex --etex --ini pdflatex.ini` will make `pdflatex.fmt and that;s all you need, That's what I do when making custom builds.

Comment: Hehe, I tried to get `install-tl` to work exactly to avoid setting correctly `TEXINPUTS` and other stuff for manual calls of fomat generation :)

Comment: Alternatively, it could be a problem with how `fmtutil.pl` (https://github.com/TeX-Live/texlive-source/raw/trunk/texk/texlive/linked_scripts/texlive/fmtutil.pl) discovers available engines

Comment: After a LOT of trouble, I made it produce `pdflatex.fmt`, but I still struggle with `lualatex.fmt`. Instead it produces `dvilualatex.fmt` :(

Comment: Okay, I managed it to produce `lualatex.fmt` as well, but I had to copy `luatex` as `luahbtex`

Comment: luahbtex should be a different binary (with harfbuzz bindings) it is not a copy or symlink to luatex.

Comment: Ideally yes, for now I just hacked around it so that it would call my binary with the stock `lualatex.ini`